# What are the fitting skills?

Tags: eve-online

Pretty simple question.

I have 33M SP account with a lot of fitting skills, yet when I do some fittings I find myself unable to understand why my account cannot fit that particular ship because of CPU/Power Grid problems.

Is there a list of fitting skills?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The skills that affect fitting are:

- **CPU Management**: 5% bonus to ship CPU output per skill level.
- **Power Grid Management**: 5% bonus to ship power grid output per skill level.
- **Energy Weapon Rigging**: 10% reduction in Energy Weapon Rig drawbacks per level.
- **Hybrid Weapon Rigging**: 10% reduction in Hybrid Weapon Rig drawbacks per level.
- **Launcher Rigging**: 10% reduction in Launcher Rig drawbacks per level.
- **Projectile Weapon Rigging**: 10% reduction in Projectile Weapon Rig drawbacks per level.
- **Armor Rigging**: 10% reduction in Armor Rig drawbacks per level.
- **Drones Rigging**: 10% reduction in Drone Rig drawbacks per level.
- **Weapon Upgrades**:  5% reduction per skill level in the CPU needs of weapon turrets, launchers and smartbombs.
- **Advanced Weapon Upgrades**: Reduces the powergrid needs of weapon turrets and launchers by 2% per skill level
- **Shield Upgrades**: 5% reduction in shield upgrade powergrid needs.
- **Energy Grid Upgrades**:  5% reduction in CPU needs of modules requiring Energy Grid Upgrades per skill level.
- **Electronics Upgrades**: 5% reduction of CPU needs for all modules requiring Electronics Upgrades per skill level.
- **Capacitor Management**:  5% bonus to capacitor capacity per skill level. *Doesn't affect fitting directly but unlocks **Micro Auxiliary Power Core II***.

The rigging skills listed above reduce a CPU or Power Grid penalty when using certain rigs.

You should be aware that CCP has done a lot rebalancing of ships over the years. This means there's lot old fittings out there that will no longer work on current ships even with max skills.  Sometimes you'll also find fittings that don't work unless you're using a certain implant that wasn't mentioned a requirement.  It's easy to put together a fitting together and publish it somewhere without realizing it depends on some implant you forgot you had plugged in.